# excel says date in June is greater than a date in July - why?

Tags: vba, excel, date, formatting

I am new to VBA and I've written a code which gets a start and stop date from report X and retrieves data from report Y where the dates lie between the start and the stop date. (e.g. 18 Jun 2018 > data form report Y < 05 Jul 2018).

Here comes the issue:
my VBA code does not run correctly since it tells me in an if-else-statement, that 18 Jun 2018 is greater than 05 Jul 2018, which cannot be true. I have tried formatting the dates but it still would't work.

```
Sub calculateCompliance()

n = 0
    ' calculate for screening
    For i = 1 To 500
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) > Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5") _
        And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) < Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F5") _
        Then
                n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E6").Value = n

End Sub
```

EDIT: By adding the variable declarations i.e. "dim startdate as Date", the errors have been resolved. This was really because of the different cell format. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cast them to `Date` types. I'll bet anything you're doing a `String` compare.

Comment: Can you post your actual code so we can see how you are reading it in?

Comment: I have formatted already both to Date format, they are not strings.

Comment: Add the code to the original question - formatted properly...

Comment: I've tested your code and it works exactly how you describe it should. I'm not getting 18 Jun 2018 as being greater than 05 Jul 2018. Listing each date from 01 Jun 2018 to 01 Aug 2018 in Sheet1 Column F, I get a result of 16 days between the two which is accurate. What is happening that would lead you to believe the comparison is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on cell types in code. Let's pull those values in and force VBA to coerce them in to Date values. Then do our comparison.

Does this work for you?

```
Sub calculateCompliance()
    Dim thisDate As Date
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date

    startDate = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")
    endDate = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F5")

    Dim n As Integer
    n = 0
    ' calculate for screening

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 500
        thisDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)
        If thisDate > startDate And thisDate < endDate Then
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E6").Value = n
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this will have the same issue, as `thisdate>startdate` will still evaluate as false if both are the same date.  Need to change the operators to `>=` and `<=` to include the start and end dates in the count.  (See my answer)

Comment: @hoffmannv didn't specify that the dates should be included. The problem was July being less than June. Your observation is correct but it won't solve the problem by itself.

Comment: @hackslash- Specifically, the "VBA code does not run correctly since it tells me in an if-else-statement, that 18 Jun 2018 is greater than 05 Jul 2018, which cannot be true."  The issue with this statement is that the code is not failing for that issue, but because 18 Jun is not greater than 18 Jun.  I copied the code to a workbook set up with the values specified and everything worked fine except that 18 Jun will not be counted for this reason.  In similar vein, 05 Jul will also not be counted, but that was not stated as a problem.  I just added that in case it should be included also.

Comment: Also, every other value between 18 Jun and 05 Jul was counted when I ran it.

Comment: But @ReyJuna, you don't have the broken workbook that OP is using. You have no idea what data is in the cells.

Comment: The dates specified were "18 Jun 2018 > data form report Y < 05 Jul 2018" and I set E5 and F5 on Sheet2 equal to those dates.  With that, the code provided worked perfectly, except for 18 Jun not being counted.

Comment: By adding the variable declarations i.e. "dim startdate as Date", the errors have been resolved. This was really because of the different cell format. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @hoffmannv That's great! If this is the answer, please click the Green checkmark so other people don't try to keep helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your comparison. If `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)` contains 18 Jun 2018 then  `IF 18 Jun 2018 > 18 Jun 2018 AND 18 Jun 2018 < 05 Jul 2018 THEN` will evaluate to false, not because it is greater than 05 Jul 2018, but because 18 Jun is not greater than 18 Jun.  If you want 18 Jun to meet your criteria, then you should make it `>=`.

So

`If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) > Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")`

would be changed to

`If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) >= Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")`

Or to incorporate @hackslash answer (and I agree that it is better to control your data in your VBA code instead of pulling it into your formulas and hoping that it matches), you would change

`If thisDate > startDate`

to

`If thisDate >= startDate`